# Unable to access ftp

Tags: browser, ftp, router

But it after entering this site in chrome url box nothing happens
If try it on brave browser it gives message to open chrome

I am trying to access ftp://192.168.1.1
On my pc

[image: click]

I want to access usb device connected to mu router

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though, this is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This isn’t a programming question and is off-topic here. There is a [duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/1634495/how-can-i-open-an-ftp-server-in-chrome) on Superuser.

Answer (score -2):

FTP is not WEB / HTTP.

Try to use a FTP Client software:

For example this free one:
https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client

---

By knowing, you want to access a server by FTP, the message

> Open Google Chrome?
> A website wants to open this application.

is a hint, that

- you didn't open the URL in Chrome, but elsewhere. This might be in another web browser a link on the Desktop of your PC or elsewhere.
- your operating system has registered Chrome as the application to use, when you try to access an URL that uses the protocol FTP.

By opening the FTP link outside of the assigned application, your request will be forwarded to the assigned application. As the system knows this is an indirect interaction `You ›› App-with-link ›› Assigned-app`, it requests if this task-transfer is that what you wanted.

I would expect that if you open the link within Google Chrome, this message should not appear.

> I want to access usb device connected to mu router

Your router takes the task to be also a NAS (Network Attached Storage) and makes the USB device accessible via FTP (File Transfer Protocol), a protocol especially designed to access remote files like those on your USB device.

So it is not usefull to delegate the job for a *file*-browser to a *web*-browser. There is no file-content to interpret. The best usability you get, if you use the fitting tool for the job.

For FTP in general this could be FileZilla (see above) to access a FTP-server in the internet. For best integration (preferably only within your LAN) this could be your file explorer / file browser. Many of them also support FTP for an almost seamless experience.

Comment: But it was working in chrome a week ago

Comment: I see, I delivered a solution, not an answer. I extended my answer to better fit to your question.